# How to optimize non-recursive flattening algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, google-apps-script, large-data, flatten

I am working with the Google Apps Script environment to create a Community Connector for Google's Data Studio. The idea of this is to call to an external API and parse the data in such a way that it's readable for Data Studio to correctly create a chart or table from.

I am currently attempting to lower load times and I've found the biggest time consumption is changing the API response from something like...

```
{
  campaigns: [{
    name_campaign: Example_Name,
    ads: [
      {cost: 15.98}
    ],
    budget: 237.59
  },
  {
    name_campaign: Another_Name,
    ads: [
      {cost: 98.25},
      {cost: 13.03},
      {cost: 23.44}
    ],
    budget: 15.50
  },
  ...
}
```

to the way Data Studio expects, which is a flat data set...

```
[
  [237.59, Example_Name, 15.98],
  [15.50, Another_Name, 98.25],
  [15.50, Another_Name, 13.03],
  [15.50, Another_Name, 23.44]
]
```

The trick is that since the call to the API is created dynamically there is no way to know how many fields or how many different objects there will be. It is possible that there's only one object with two fields or something similar to above. Luckily it has been restricted to only having parent/child relationships instead of siblings.

The algorithm so far is a non-recursive loop that finds the deepest object and retains all the fields in the last object/loop. If there are deeper objects then it repeats this process. If not then it takes the lowest object's fields and all previously stored fields, concats them together, and appends them as a row to be returned. The code is commented with the logic as well, which will hopefully be helpful.

```
function stackIt(data) {
  var totalData = [];

  //create stack with highest object
  var stack = [{
    v: data,
    parent_fields: []
  }];

  var stackLen = stack.length;
  var pushing = 0, totalFields = 0;
  var data_fields, array_field, cl, v, current_fields, temp, arr_len, row, parentFields;

  while (stackLen > 0) {
    //store current node 
    cl = stack.pop();
    if (cl === undefined)
      break;

    v = cl.v;
    parentFields = cl.parent_fields.slice(0);

    //fill new array with all parents
    data_fields = parentFields.slice(0);
    array_field = null;
    current_fields = [];

    //Does another object exist?
    //Keep track of all current fields on the chance that no objects exists below
    for (var field in v) {
      //Hold the current field
      temp = v[field];
      current_fields.push(temp);

      //found an object. So we know we need to move deeper with the current object
      if (typeof(temp) === 'object' && temp != null && array_field == null)
        array_field = field;
      //store current parent fields
      if (typeof(temp) !== "object")
        data_fields.push(temp)
    }

    //Push new node to stack to delve deeper
    //each one with with parent data points to tack on later for deepest level objects
    if (array_field != null) {
      for (var i = 0, arr_len = v[array_field].length; i < arr_len; i++) {
        //Skip broken fields
        if ('errors' in v[array_field][i])
          continue;

        stack.push({
          v: v[array_field][i],
          parent_fields: data_fields
        });
      }      
    }
    //No object exists below
    else {
      row = [];
      //re set data fields if no object was found
      //data_fields is changed in above function on the chance that there is an object below
      data_fields = parentFields.slice(0);

      //get total number of fields that should exist
      //this is to prevent pushing rows with only a subset of fields
      //only do once at deepest object to get total number of fields expected
      if (pushing == 0) {
        pushing = 1;
        totalFields = data_fields.length + current_fields.length;
      }

      //push parents fields (ex. camp.cost)
      row = data_fields.splice(0);

      //push all current fields held (ex. keyword.cost)
      row = row.concat(current_fields);
      //comes out to camp.cost, keyword.cost

      //Push all rows at lowest level; exit if done.
      if (row.length != totalFields) {
        console.log("End Stack"); 
        return totalData;
      }
      else
        totalData.push(row);
    }
  }

  console.log("End Stack with empty stack"); 
  return totalData;
}
```

I've tried using the open source library `cFlatten` but that made the flattening much slower and most of the tools I found only require only 1-2 objects deep and require a specifc formatting for them. The algorithm used to be recursive but since the amount of data being returned is so large it was much slower. Any ideas on how to make the function faster/more efficient would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont see this working if an object has more than 1 array field or more than 1 object field or 1 array and 1 object field

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.push.apply(row, current_fields);` Maybe try sorting the input campaign array, such that you get the deepest object first and can construct the object-array relationship immediately, after which you just try to push that value, defaulting to `undefined`/`null` as appropriate. Alternately, hide the delay by asking the user which headers they want from each object level, during which you parse the connection and map the total arrangement.